# Lat and Long in android

Tags: android

I have 300 lat long numbers stored in DB in MySQL remote server. I would like to Calculate the difference between current lat and long from my phone and the lat, long in my DB remotely. O

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking send the current lat and long from the phone and do the calculation and send the difference back?

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a limited number of locations, hash/cache them into the local memory when the app restarts and use it from there, otherwise, build a webservice that calls the server with the phone lon-lat and let the server return the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300 is not a lot of data points. I have an app with over 50,000 and it's no problem at all.

I would send the database from the remote server to your phone (or a subset of the columns anyway).

In my own app, I divided the world into 1°x1° sectors and assigned sector numbers with

```
sector = (lat+90)*360 + (lon+180);
```

effectively hashing them. The hash code is part of the database.

Then, when I want to look for nearby data points, I compute the sector number for the current latitude and longitude, and for the eight adjacent sectors as well. I then limit my database search to those nine sectors.

After that, just query the database for data points in those nearby sectors, and compute the distances between my current location and those data points.

There's the one-time cost of downloading the database into your phone, but it saves significant time and bandwidth later.